# Lower back pain when stretching hamstrings

Tags: pain, core, back-pain, lower-back

I went to defence forces 4 months ago and have had intense training and stuff without no good physical base before.

Had to carry a 60 pound bag for miles on my back etc and now having lower back pain when doing [stretches for hamstring](http://physicaltherapy.about.com/od/flexibilityexercises/a/hamstingstretch_3.htm).

It seems that joints do not hurt, and only lower back muscles. I googled around a little bit, and it seems like muscle imbalance? Like lower back muscles are not strong enough or something. I am not sure.

Can someone please help me with this problem? What could be wrong with me.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to answer this question in a responsible manner, it is better to consult a physician here.

Comment: Yeah, we can't give you any sort of definite answer ,but here are some things that _could_ be wrong... Maybe your pack wasn't fitted properly to you, or you didn't use the waist support properly. A proper fitting pack stress the lower back very minimally, even if heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Your hamstrings attach near your lower back. It could merely be that you are feeling the hamstring stretch near where they attach - thus if it's only a mild pain I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Disagree, pain is your bodies way of telling you something is wrong , thus it shouldn't be ignored. I would say its unusual to feel a hamstring stretch in the lower back before the main body of the hamstring.

Answer (score 0):

Your hamstrings attach on your Ischial Tuberosity (your "sit bones", like when you tell someone they have a boney butt if they sit in your lap).  Your Erector Spinae muscles are a group of muscles that run up your spine.  Part of this group is the Iliocostalis that originates along your Sacrum (tail bone) and Iliac crest (your hip bone).

I am assuming that when you stretch for your hamstrings you are letting your back round out.  This would allow the lower part of your back to stretch as well. Adding a 60 pound pack while doing PT is a lot of change for your body.  If the pain is mildly uncomfortable but just "sore" your pain could be a few things.  If your pain is hindering your range of motion or sends sharp pains anywhere you should go see a doctor as soon as you can. If you don't normally feel a lot of pain you should go regardless because your body might not be able to sense how hurt it really is.

If it is a muscle imbalance I would be willing to bet your lower abdominal muscles are under-developed compared to your back and your hip flexors are tight. Any of the exercises [here](http://www.sixpackfactory.com/straight-leg-raise/) should do the job for the lower abs.  As a side note, I did not notice them tell you in the videos but your hands should be on the hamstring side of your hips (not in your lower back).  This help keep your lower back in the floor, relieving the stress place upon it. You can stretch your hip flexors by performing [this](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/stretching/SM00043&slide=5) stretch.

If you do not feel comfortable doing this on your own, ask a trainer or someone in your unit that is more familiar with having "perfect" form while doing exercise.